# Do you get Notifications from Adium IRC on Mac?

Tags: mac, irc, adium

Previously I was using LimeChat for my IRC client on Mac and was getting notifications fine.
But I started using Adium and notifications don't show up, I have to go to Adium and read the messages. 
Is it something I haven't setup correctly? or it is how Adium on Mac works?

**Please Note:** I DO get notification on screen if someone is sending me a direct message or mentions my name in a room But with LimeChat I was able to see all things that people post in the rooms as notifications on the scree. And that's the part I couldn't get to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up notifications in Adium's preferences under *Events*.

[image: Screenshot]